# Problem in solving inequality by wavy curve method

Tags: inequality

Please help me in solving this question:

> Find the solution set of $x $ for which the expression $$ \frac {x (3^x -1)(x+1)^2}{(x-3)(x-2)^4} $$ is **positive**.

My problem is that if I use the **wavy curve method**, then what should be the critical point for $3^x-1 \; $?

Secondly, **positive** means $\gt 0 \;$ or $\ge 0 \;$?

The answer given is: $x \in (3, \infty) \quad $.

Comment: For second part positive means >0. 0 is considered to be neither positive nor negative.

Comment: $3^x>0$ for all $x$, so $3^x-1>-1$. The only time it equals zero is when $x= 0$.

Comment: HINT:$$ (x+1)^2>0$$ if $$x\ne -1$$ and $$(x-2)^4>0$$ if $$x\ne 2$$

Comment: Well, then I have critical point 0 for both $x $ and $3^x -1$. It'll be open as the expression is $\gt 0$. So, at 0, will the graph change direction (change from below to above the line or vice-versa) or remain in same direction?

Comment: Note $x(3^x-1), (x+1)^2, (x-2)^4$ are non-negative... What remains is a single sign change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous function may change its sign only at its zeros (here $0$ and $-1$) and where it's undefined (here $3$ and $2$). This gives five intervals,  and on each of those intervals the sign is constant.  De facto we have only two candidates for a change of sign, namely $0$ and $3$, as the sign surely doesn't change at $-1$ and $2$.  So this gives the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$, $(0,3)$ and $(3,\infty)$. Only on the last one the expression is positive.

Comment: Five intervals viz. $(- \infty, -1) $, $(-1, 0) $, $(0, 2) $, $(2,3) $ and $(3,\infty) \quad $, right? What brings in 1 as a critical point? I'm getting critical points $-1$, 0, 2 and 3.

Comment: Well, $0$ is the zero of $3^x-1$.

Comment: And of the lone $x $????

Comment: It equals zero iff $x=0$, doesn't it?

Comment: True, then what'should the critical point for that?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58519/discussion-between-wrichik-basu-and-michael-hoppe).

Answer (score 3):

less wavy....................................

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put $(3^x-1)=0$ and take $log_{10}$ both sides.You will get $log_{10}(3^x)=log_{10}1$. i.e. $xlog(3)=0$ hence critical point is $x=0$ as $log_{10}3=0.471$.(as $log_{10}1=0$ and $log(a^b)=blog(a)$)

Comment: Well, then I have critical point 0 for both $x $ and $3^x -1$. It'll be open as the expression is $\gt 0$. So, at 0, will the graph change direction (change from below to above the line or vice-versa) or remain in same direction?

Comment: try to put a value greater and less than 0 and see if the sign changes. Or you can also find the concavity of graph by using differentiation.

Comment: I'm not of pure maths, don't puzzle me with concavity........